# How to fund account for parity private chain?

Tags: parity, metamask, parity-wallet

I'm having trouble funding accounts when starting parity with a custom chain. My json file is

```
{
    "name": "DevelopmentChain",
    "engine": {
        "instantSeal": null
    },
    "params": {
        "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x0400",
        "accountStartNonce": "0x0",
        "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
        "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
        "networkID" : "0x11",
        "registrar" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001337",
        "eip150Transition": "0x0",
        "eip160Transition": "0x0",
        "eip161abcTransition": "0x0",
        "eip161dTransition": "0x0",
        "eip155Transition": "0x0",
        "eip98Transition": "0x7fffffffffffff",
        "eip86Transition": "0x7fffffffffffff",
        "maxCodeSize": 24576,
        "maxCodeSizeTransition": "0x0",
        "eip140Transition": "0x0",
        "eip211Transition": "0x0",
        "eip214Transition": "0x0",
        "eip658Transition": "0x0",
        "wasmActivationTransition": "0x0"
    },
    "genesis": {
        "seal": {
            "generic": "0x0"
        },
        "difficulty": "0x20000",
        "author": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "timestamp": "0x00",
        "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "extraData": "0x",
        "gasLimit": "0x7A1200"
    },
    "accounts": {
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } },
        "0x1f9945a4DBe3851beDc787434d2A63dd44303f77": { "balance": "10" },
        "0x68Ff636CA053Adb00804923ef1e23bA729760cf6": { "balance": "12" },
        "0x14fE6Fc199DdaB2b94b8d4bf8664c86a4d275711": { "balance": "13" }
    }
}
```

which is based on [this example](https://wiki.parity.io/Private-development-chain#customizing-the-development-chain).

I start my local parity node with `parity --chain parity-dev.json --unsafe-expose --jsonrpc-cors="all"`. However, whenever I connect to parity with metamask none of the accounts (`0x1f9945a4DBe3851beDc787434d2A63dd44303f77`, `0x68Ff636CA053Adb00804923ef1e23bA729760cf6` and `0x14fE6Fc199DdaB2b94b8d4bf8664c86a4d275711`) have any balance shown. Similarly, when I open the parity UI and check the wallet, I don't see any accounts:

Here's what I see on metamask for one of the accounts which should have a balance.
[image: Account on metamask]

Here's what I see in the parity ui wallet (note `PARITY-DEV.JSON` in the top right):

[image: Parity UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the balance is in wei which is why it wasn't showing up. I changed `"0x1f9945a4DBe3851beDc787434d2A63dd44303f77": { "balance": "10" },` to `"0x1f9945a4DBe3851beDc787434d2A63dd44303f77": { "balance": "100000000000000000" },` (added 18 zeros) and it all works now.

Shoutout to @tbaut on the gitter channel: https://gitter.im/paritytech/parity?at=5b5f2cb8d4527523f640622e